# Nginx: Redirect subdomains to subfolder

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I have the following url structure:

```
domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.xy
```

The folder 1 is always there and what follows is completely flexible and different. For example there could also be:

```
domain.com/folder1/file.xy
```

So basically it is

```
domain.com/folder1/*
```

What I want to achieve now is that I am able to open the subdomain:

```
folder1.domain.com/*
```

with any folder/file at the end and nginx automatically knows that the subdomain is equal to the first subfolder so that the request with the subdomain would be equal to

```
domain.com/folder1/*
```

How am I able to achieve this with nginx?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Just to clarify it a bit more: the "folder1" can be anything. So basically any subdomain is equal to the first subfolder.

Comment: You must define each subdomain with different root directory.

Comment: See [this example](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) of using a regular expression `server_name` to set `root`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [Regular expressions names](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names)

Your server block would look like that

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name   "~^(?<folder>.+)\.domain\.com$" ;
    location / {
        root   /srv/http/$folder;
    }
}
```